# Access Magento Connect Manager Without Using Admin Panel

Tags: magento-connect-manager

Is it possible to access my Magento Connect Manager without using the Admin dashboard?

I installed an extension that has locked up my site, even my admin page. I need to go through a backway to uninstall that extension. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using the magento connect from the command line tool. 
Login to your server and from the magento root type:
`./mage`

If you get the following error message `./mage: Permission denied` you'll need to make the file executable `chmod +x mage`.

Now when you run `./mage` you should get a list of options:

```
Connect commands available:
===========================
channel-add          Add a Channel
channel-alias        Specify an alias to a channel name
channel-delete       Remove a Channel From the List
channel-info         Retrieve Information on a Channel
channel-login        Connects and authenticates to remote channel server
channel-logout       Logs out from the remote channel server
clear-cache          Clear Web Services Cache
config-get           Show One Setting
config-help          Show Information About Setting
config-set           Change Setting
config-show          Show All Settings
convert              Convert old magento PEAR package to new format
download             Download Package
info                 Display information about a package
install              Install Package
install-file         Install Package Archive File
list-available       List Available Packages
list-channels        List Available Channels
list-files           List Files In Installed Package
list-installed       List Installed Packages In The Default Channel
list-upgrades        List Available Upgrades
package              Build Package
package-dependencies Show package dependencies
package-prepare      Show installation information of package
sync                 Synchronize Manually Installed Packages
sync-pear            Synchronize already Installed Packages by pear
uninstall            Un-install Package
upgrade              Upgrade Package
upgrade-all          Upgrade All Packages
```

From here you should now be able to do the following: `./mage uninstall {package_name}.

While your here i'd also recommend installing N98-magerun (https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) tool.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly goto the connect manager by using the below link

your_site_url/downloader/

Comment: And also you manually disable the installed extension by app/etc/modules/yourextension.xml and change true to false in the active tag.